# How do I make my recursive function for a Fibonacci series print out ever number in the series up to the limit(argument)

Tags: python, function, recursion, fibonacci

I have am trying to create a recursive function in Python that takes an argument as a limit and prints out all numbers in the Fibonacci series up to that limit. For example, if the argument is 5  the output should be 1, 1, 2, 3, 5

```py
def fib(n):
    """Returns fibonnaci series using recursion"""
    if n <= 1:
        return (n)
    else:
        return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2))
```

This only gives me the output of 5 instead of the whole series

Comment: Where are you stuck?  You simply `print` every value before you return it.

Comment: As in I put : print(fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)) above return (fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)) ?

Comment: You want to print something, but don't have a print anywhere in the function. That should be a somewhat red flag, yes?

Comment: Or return it, once I put in an argument of 4 it only returns 3 rather than 1, 1, 2, 3

Comment: Asking whether something *will* work is not effective on SO (Stack Overflow) ... you have the ultimate authority in front of you.  Try it!

Comment: Didn't work, returned 1
2
1
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
5
1
2
1
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
3
1
2
1
1
8
1
2
1
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
5
1
2
1
1
3
1
2
1
1
1
2
1
1
2
1
1
3
1
2
1
1

Answer (score 0):

Example of recursive fibonacci up to a limit

```
def fib(limit, cache = None):
  if cache == None:
    cache = [1, 1]

  cache.append(sum(cache[-2:]))

  if cache[-1] > limit:
    # Done-- don't include last item in list
    #        since its over the limit
    return cache[:-1]
  else:
    # Extend cache with recursive call to 
    #        generate next fibonacci
    return fib(limit, cache)

# Test generation
for k in range(1, 10):
  print(k, fib(k))
```

Output

```
1 [1, 1]
2 [1, 1, 2]
3 [1, 1, 2, 3]
4 [1, 1, 2, 3]
5 [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
6 [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
7 [1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
8 [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
9 [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]
```